# Settings kafka producer within pentaho

Tags: apache-kafka, pentaho, kafka-producer-api

I'm setting kafka producer...

I have a topic with 20 partitions, I have verified that only one partition is being filled

Below settings
[the producer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ULu11.jpg)

[settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1LZut.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide more information.

With the given information I think that the problem is that you have the same message key for all sent messages, which results in the same partition assignment by default partitioner. If it's like this then you have 2 options:

1. Hardcode the partition number in ProducerRecord.
2. Create a custom Partitioner.

Comment: Is that I do not have more information, I'm just using the kafka lib in pentaho, and I used it according to their website [link](https://github.com/RuckusWirelessIL/pentaho-kafka-producer)

Comment: Well then you can raise an issue there, asking how the send kafka messages... Don't think that with this amount of given information about kafka you can have a better answer.

Comment: I agree, I already sent them to them. I did not have any answer :-D